# Android: How do you create spinners that look the same in an activity?

Tags: android, spinner

**Edit: Fixed it by using the same adapter on both spinners.**

I have two spinners in an activity and they look completely different. One looks like its touch friendly and the other doesn't. How do I make them use the same design?

```
Spinner spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
        this, R.array.raddix_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinner1.setAdapter(adapter);

Spinner spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter2 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
        this, R.array.raddix_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinner2.setAdapter(adapter2);

spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
spinner2.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would imagine that this is somewhere in the XML that defines the two spinners. Ensure that all of the relevant properties are the same within the XML (such as enabled).

Comment: both are using the same exact xml code with the exception of the id for the names.